# Strange Problem, Navigation Code Only Works In The Morning (California Time)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I've encountered a strange problem where this code only runs in the morning (12am ~ 6am) California time.

```
 Directions.shared.calculate(options){ (session, result) in
        
        print("Here: \(result)")
        guard case let .success(response) = result,
            let route = response.routes?.first else{
                print("This did't work")
                return
        }
```

It's been happening for the past two days. I don't think it's on my end but what should I do? This is for the iOS-Navigation-SDK.

I get the error:

```
 failure(MapboxDirections.DirectionsError.unableToRoute)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is reading this and having the same issue, they're upgrading their service early July. Just wait for the update and problem solved.